# How to make a Vue.js component of some (but not all) table cells in a table row?

Tags: html, templates, vue.js, html-table

I have some related and neighboring table columns that I would like to group in the same component. But the Vue.js template system has this limitation that only one tag can be directly in `<template>`. Often this meaningless wrapper is a `<div>`. But what can I use in a table?

I can abuse tags like `<span>` for that, but the consequences are not acceptable. The cells in the same column do not have the same size, and the table borders do not  collapse. Is there a way to have a wrapper tag that ideally will not show up in the HTML at all, or will at least be as neutral as a `<div>`?

Table row:

```
<template>
    <tr v-for="thing in things">
        <td>{{thing.name}}</td>
        <size-component :size="thing.size"></size-component>
        <time-component :time="thing.time"></time-component>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Size columns:

```
<template>
    <wrap>
        <td>{{size.x}}</td>
        <td>{{size.y}}</td>
        <td>{{size.z}}</td>
    </wrap>
</template>
```

Time columns:

```
<template>
    <wrap>
        <td>{{time.h}}</td>
        <td>{{time.m}}</td>
        <td>{{time.s}}</td>
    </wrap>
</template>
```

---

**Edit:**
To me this boils down to the problem, that there is no tag to group `<td>`s in a `<tr>` (like `<tr>`s can be grouped in `<table>` with multiple `<tbody>` tags). Compare [Is there a tag for grouping "td" or "th" tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028535/is-there-a-tag-for-grouping-td-or-th-tags)
Semantically `<colgroup>` is intended for this purpose, but that does not help.
For me using [vue-fragment](https://github.com/y-nk/vue-fragment) turned out to be the right solution:

```
<template>
    <fragment>
        <td>{{size.x}}</td>
        <td>{{size.y}}</td>
        <td>{{size.z}}</td>
        <td>{{volume}}</td>
    </fragment>
</template>

<script>
    import { Fragment } from 'vue-fragment';

    export default {
        computed: {
            volume() { return this.size.x * this.size.y * this.size.z },
        },
        components: { Fragment },
        props: ['size']
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, this is a limitation with Vue and has something to do with [the diffing algorithm](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7088#issuecomment-348252040). You can, however, use a functional component to render multiple root elements.

```
<script>
export default {
  functional: true,
  props: {
    size: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({
        x: 1,
        y: 2,
        z: 3
      })
    }
  },
  render: (createElement, context) => [
    createElement('td', context.props.size.x),
    createElement('td', context.props.size.y),
    createElement('td', context.props.size.z)
  ]
}
</script>
```

Another option is to use the plugin [vue-fragments](https://github.com/y-nk/vue-fragment)

Comment: Wow, what a messy topic. Do you know how I could use computed properties in `createElement`? Let's say there is `volume() { return size.x * size.y * size.z }`. The intuitive solution would be `context.computed.volume`, but that does not work.

Comment: Ok, functional components are stateless, so if I understand it correctly, they are not supposed to have something like `volume()`. I get the impression that what I want can not be done without increasing the complexity to a degree that I don't want to deal with. The whole point was to reduce complexity by having a few small components instead of a big one.

Comment: Yesterday I did not get vue-fragment to work, but that turned out to be the easiest solution. Thanks.

Comment: `vue-fragment` was my preference, a bit like [portal-vue](https://linusborg.github.io/portal-vue/#/guide) but simpler syntax.

Answer (score 1):

To add computed to @Andreas solution, can reference a parent property.

Demo [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0454jn66xw)

**functional component**

```js
export default {
  functional: true,
  props: {
    size: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({
        x: 1,
        y: 2,
        z: 3
      })
    }
  },
  render: (createElement, context) => [
    createElement("td", context.props.size.x),
    createElement("td", context.props.size.y),
    createElement("td", context.props.size.z),
    createElement("td", context.parent.volume(context.props.size))
  ]
};
```

**parent component**

```js
export default {
  components: {
    SizeComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      things: [
        {
          name: 'aName',
          size: { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // test it is reactive
    setTimeout(()=> { this.things[0].size.x = 2 }, 3000) 
  },
  computed: {
    volume() {
      return (size) => size.x * size.y * size.z;
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for completing the answer. I am sure this will help someone. Anyway, I find this too complicated. I think I will instead switch from `<table>` to `display: table`. So the simple solution should be the good old `<div>`.

Comment: I hope you will post an answer with your preferred solution.

Comment: Switching from `<table>` to `display: table` did not work, BTW. Same problem.