# Is there any way to have a tag between table-row and table-cell in a CSS table?

Tags: html, css-tables

There can be no tag between `<tr>` and `<td>` in an HTML table. ([Is there a tag for grouping "td" or "th" tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028535/is-there-a-tag-for-grouping-td-or-th-tags)) But is there any way to have such a grouping tag that between `<div>`s with `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell`?

This may seem silly, but the point is that I want to add behavior like `@mouseover="doSomething"` or `:class="{someClass: someCondition}"` in a Vue.js application, and I need a tag for that. I don't want to add behavior to the whole row, and to stay DRY I would rather not add it to each cell individually.

---

**Edit:** HTML does not offer a solution, but in Vue I was able to get the desired result using *vue-fragment*. It allows to attach behaviour to the dummy `<fragment>` tag. Example: [MatrixRLabel](https://github.com/watchduck/DAG/blob/master/front/app/src/components/MatrixRLabel.vue) in [MatrixR](https://github.com/watchduck/DAG/blob/master/front/app/src/components/MatrixR.vue) (Those are the beige labels in the upper matrix in [this app](http://dag.watchduck.net/?edges=0-1~0-2~0-4~1-3~1-5~2-3~2-6~3-7~4-5~4-6~5-7~6-7&names=000~001~010~011~100~101~110~111).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` applies a certain relationship to the parent and child divs. Just like with `<tr>` and `<td>`, adding a div "in between them" obviously disrupts this relationship, and causes results I cannot meaningfully predict without a bit of research.

So yes, you will have to apply the behavior to the desired cells individually.

```
<tr>
    <td @mouseover="doSomething">...</td>
    <td @mouseover="doSomething">...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Alternatively, you can identify those cells with a class and then have the behavior check for that class before executing.

```
<tr @mouseover="doSomething">
    <td class="onlyToMe">...</td>
    <td class="onlyToMe">...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Since you haven't gotten an answer before this, perhaps you've figured something out yourself? Do share if you can. Cheers!